# System.IO.IOException being used by another process

Tags: c#, io, ioexception

I am trying to write to a file, I believe i am closing the file that i had read in earlier in the code, but I am getting a "System.IO.IO.Exception" This is my code for reading and writing to the file.

```
public class InOutTxt
{
    public List<Employee> ReadFile(string fileName) {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open ,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(fileName);
        fileIn = File.OpenText(fileName);
        List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
        string[] test;
        string name;
        string ID;
        string dep;
        string post;

        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream || !File.Exists(fileName)) {

            string inString = fileIn.ReadLine();
            test = inString.Split('#');
            name = test[0];
            ID = test[1];
            dep = test[2];
            post = test[3];
            Employee newEmp = new Employee(name, ID, dep, post);
            list.Add(newEmp);

        }
        fileIn.Close();
        fs.Close();
        return list;
    }

    public void WriteFile(List<Employee> outList, string file) {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter writeOut = new StreamWriter(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < outList.Count; i++) {

            writeOut.WriteLine(outList[i].name + '#' + outList[i].IDnum + '#' + outList[i].department + '#' + outList[i].position);

        }
        writeOut.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }

}
```

The Error is occuring at this part of the code

```
StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(fileName);
```

If it helps any it was running well earlier today, the only major change I have made was the addition of the FileStream attribute above.

Comment: You open 3 files but you close only 2.  The bug is in the 2nd line of code, that doesn't do anything.  You stop making mistakes like this by using the *using* statement.

Answer (score 1):

> System.IO.IOException being used by another process

You have opened file using the `FileStream` constructor and the `StreamReader` gives error when it tries to open the file again using the fileName constructor. Pass the `FileStream` object instead of `fileName`.

[FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The constructor is given read/write access to the file, and it is
>   opened sharing Read access (that is, requests to open the file for
>   writing by this or another process will fail until the FileStream
>   object has been closed, but read attempts will succeed), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
//File is opened by FileStream and not available for opening before it is closed.
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open ,FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(fs); //Here pass fs instead of fileName
```